# Pass Argument To Method Containing Block and Assign Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have method which contains an animation block.  I am trying to pass a class property as an argument to the method, and assign it a value of nil inside the block.

```
-(void)endPinching:(UIViewController *)pinchedController{

    // a bunch of code

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        //do stuff

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

       // do other stuff

        pinchedController = nil; //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
    }];
  }
}
```

So, if I call this method in the class that it is called in, pinchController is self.pinchController and therefore can be set to nil inside the block.  But here, in the definition, I get a compiler error:

```
"variable not assignable, missing block type specifier"
```

So, I tried adding the block specifier by doing:

```
__block pinchedController = nil;
```

The the compiler says:

```
"unused variable pinchedViewController"
```

I assume this means that pinchedController is now being considered a new variable and is not associated with the method parameter.

My question is: is there a way to pass in pinchedViewController as an argument and assign it to nil inside this block?

Comment: what's the point of setting a local variable (to `nil` in this case) and then not using it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to explicitly deallocate the given object. This is impossible because of how reference counting works.

By passing the `UIViewController` to `endPinching:`, you're increasing the refcount of the object by one. Setting the pointer (which is a local variable on the stack) to `nil` will only decrease the reference count by 1, but because this is still an instance variable of your class, it won't get deallocated.

So first, you should ask yourself why you'd want to deallocate such object. This can be solved by better designing your code or trying to figure out why your view controller occupies a large amount of memory.

If you still want to deallocate, you can set `self.pinchController = nil` explicitly in your method or call some kind of delegate that will do that (I need to see the entire view controller design to be more specific).

Comment: Almost;  in this case `pinchedController` is an argument to the method and that argument will be long, long, gone by the time that the completion block is run (since animations are asynchronous).  Thus, the `pinchedController` implied strong reference in that argument is dead and gone.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the completion block should hold a strong reference to all of it's closure, capturing `pinchedController` too. No?

Comment: Yes, but that reference is a retained copy.  The `pinchedController` argument/local variable is long gone because the `endPinching:` method has returned long before the completion box is executed.

Comment: Oh, of course. What I tried to say is that setting a `nil` to a stack variable (doesn't matter if it's the function's stack or the block's) doesn't work.